# Should users be able to downvote for the answers of their own questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges

I know there is a reputation limit of 125 for downvote. But in some cases the question asker knows if the answer is useful or not, if it answers to his question or not. However he/she is not able to downvote for the answers which are off-question, or not useful at all.

Why SO restricts downvotes for even the answers of my own question? Well, keep the restriction for other Q/A, but should you give me control over my own battle?

For example, [my very new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22544615/3332579) has a very not-useful answer, and I really want to downvote that because it is not the answer to my  question.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I downvote unhelpful answers on my own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221446/why-cant-i-downvote-unhelpful-answers-on-my-own-question)

Comment: That brings up a good point: OP tests whether a answer is right or not - there are only 2 possibilities. Others just vote and hope that the voting will properly sort answers by relevance... So should OP's buttons be accept and downvote, without an upvote button? Or should downvoting be a totally separate concept when it's from the OP?

Comment: @bjb568, for own questions, it should be how it is for 125+ rep users, I think.

Comment: You could also give the answerer some time to work on his answer. He is trying to help you... It seems to me you rushed to MSO very fast after his answer.