# Can users with <125 rep downvote answers to their own questions?

Tags: support, down-votes

According to [the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), users can downvote questions or answers when their rep is >= 125.

Is there any special exemption for when it's an answer to their *own* question? (As there is with commments?)

Comment: Discussed before, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221446/why-cant-i-downvote-unhelpful-answers-on-my-own-question?lq=1).

Comment: And here's a feature request to add the feature.. [Should users be able to downvote for the answers of their own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226227/182513)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. Users can downvote posts only when they reached 125 rep with no exception to answers on their own questions (except private betas, where users can downvote having 1 rep), downvotes on questions are free and downvotes on answers cost 1 rep.

Comment: I was sort of hoping for some sort of citation. :-) Something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221446/why-cant-i-downvote-unhelpful-answers-on-my-own-question?lq=1) posted by Shadow Wizard above. If <125 users could downvote answers to their own questions, that question probably wouldn't have been asked, and if it had been the answer would have been "you already can." :-) Since those things didn't happen, I believe you're correct: There is no exemption.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't have time for citation because was afraid that someone will be faster :-)

Comment: Guess you have some time to find out now? And FGITW isn't a good excuse.

Comment: @Oded What do I need to find out? "And FGITW isn't a good excuse" - It is not an excuse at all. Why do I need to excuse?..

Comment: Well, your comment above certainly *sounded* like an excuse. I'm with @Oded: Much better to post a *good* answer than to post the *first* answer. Had Shadow Wizard posted an answer hours after yours saying "No, otherwise [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221446/why-cant-i-downvote-unhelpful-answers-on-my-own-question?lq=1) wouldn't have been asked or would have different answers." rather than his comment, I'd've accepted it instead.